# Presentation of $A_5 \times \Bbb Z_2$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap, group-presentation

I want presentation of the group $A_5\times \Bbb Z_2$ which is a group of order $120.$

I know the presentation of $A_5$ but not of product.

I tried it in GAP . In GAP its Atlas name is $2\times A_5$  but I can't type $\times $ in computer. Please given me its presentation and how I write it in GAP. Thank you very much.

Comment: There's no such thing as **the** presentation of a group; there is infinitely many! Also, it's fairly standard to get a presentation of the direct product of two groups, given a presentation of each. Search engines are some of your friends.

Comment: [Related.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2376694/104041)

Comment: Thanks ... Please give me presentation of this group only ..thanks

Comment: You're welcome, @Yogesh; see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** If $\langle X\mid R\rangle$ is a presentation of $A_5$, then $$\langle X\cup\{z\}\mid \{z^2\}\cup R\cup\{xz=zx\mid x\in X\}\rangle$$ for some symbol $z\notin X$, is a presentation of $A_5\times\Bbb Z_2$, since $\Bbb Z_2$ has $\langle z\mid z^2\rangle$ as a presentation; see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2376694/104041).

---

[This chapter of the GAP Reference Manual](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap49_mj.html) explains how to implement direct products in GAP.

Comment: Thanks for for quick reply ... I am trying to understand this answer ...

Comment: You're welcome, @Yogesh.

Comment: NB: I made a slight, technical edit, @Yogesh.

Comment: thanks sir you explain every thing very nicely ... my final question is in GAP this group name is $2\times A5$? Am I right...

Comment: Again, you're welcome, @Yogesh; as to your final question: I don't know. The library of small groups in GAP is vast. However, once you have implemented some finitely presented group object `G` in GAP, you can use the code `StructureDescription(G);` to give you what the group name is. Note, though, that it might not always output something. There's only so much that can be stored.

Comment: In GAP, `IsomorphismFpGroup` will determine a presentation for a given group, `IsomorphismFpGroupByGenerators` a presentation o a chosen generating set.

Comment: In GAP, you cannot generate groups from a name, but e.g. from Permutation generators, or as products of existing groups, e.g. `DirectProduct`.

Comment: @ahulpke thanks I will try to generate ...