# Why is $\langle a,b|bab^{-1} a^{-1},a a \rangle$ isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2 \oplus \Bbb Z$?

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation

Why is $\langle a,b|bab^{-1} a^{-1},a a \rangle$ isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2 \oplus \Bbb Z$?

Comment: $a$ is the generator of the $\mathbb{Z}_2$, which you can see from the relation $aa$, and $b$ is a generator of the $\mathbb{Z}$, and that group is abelian, so you need the relation $bab^{-1}a^{-1}$. I hope that helps.

Comment: [Related.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2376694/104041)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some observations.

The first relation tells u $a,b$ commute . The second relarion tells u $a^2=id$ So u have an abelian group $G$ generated by $<a,b>$ such that $a^2=id$

Consider the surjective $\mathbb Z-module $ homomorphism $$\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z \rightarrow G$$ given by 
$$(1,0) \mapsto b$$
$$(0,1) \mapsto a$$

Compute the kernel of this and you will get $Ker = \mathbb Z.(0,2)$
Thus $$G\cong \frac {\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z}{\mathbb Z. (0,2)} \cong \mathbb Z\oplus  \mathbb Z_2$$

Problems like this can also be solved using algebraic topology. Consider $S^1$ with  CW structure as $*\subset S^1$ and $\mathbb R\mathbb P^2$ with CW structure $*\subset S^1\cong \mathbb R \mathbb P^1 \subset \mathbb R \mathbb P^2$.

Now look at $X = S^1 \times \mathbb R \mathbb P^2$ 
$$\pi_1(X)= \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z_2$$

But you can also compute the fundamental group explicitly from the product CW structure on $X$ . The product CW structure has $one \ 0-cell$, $ two \ 1-cell's$ and $two \ 2-cells$. The $1th \ skeleton$ is a wedge of two circles labelled $a,b$ The 1st $2-cell$ is pasted along $aa$ corresponding to the $(2-cell \ \  of \mathbb R \mathbb P^2 \ )\times  (0-cell \ of \ S^1)$ and the other $2-cell$ is pasted along $bab^{-1}a^{-1}$. Then Van Kampens theorem gives u $$\pi_1(X)=<a,b|bab^{-1}a^{-1} ,aa>$$

This gives u a purely topological proof

Comment: Use `$\langle X\rangle$` for $\langle X\rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

Because $b$ is free besides the commutator $[b,a]=bab^{-1}a^{-1}$ being the identity, $aa=a^2=e$ means $a$ has order two, and those are the only relators. Hence

\begin{align}
\Bbb Z_2\oplus\Bbb Z&\cong
\langle a\mid a^2\rangle\oplus\langle b\mid\rangle \\
&\cong\langle a, b\mid a^2, [b, a]\rangle \\
&\cong \langle a, b\mid bab^{-1}a^{-1}, aa\rangle
\end{align}

as desired.