# Determining group structure after computing homology: $\langle b,c \mid 2(b+c)=0, b+c=c+b \rangle.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

I am trying to determine what group this is a presentation of:
$$\langle b,c \mid 2(b+c)=0, b+c=c+b \rangle.$$
I am pretty sure it is $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, but am stuck on how to show it.

Comment: $bc=cb$ means that $G$ is abelian. $G$ is one-relator so it's infinite. Then it's generated by $b$ of infinite order and $bc$, of order $2$. Furthermore, $\langle b\rangle$ and $\langle c\rangle$ intersect trivially. But you might want to make your presentation consistent: it's a mixture of additive and multiplicative notation.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Ah yes, I see now that 2(b+c)=0 just means that the element b+c has order 2. Then I could replace the generator c by b+c to get <b,b+c | 2(b+c)=0, b+c=c+b> and easily see that this is Z x Z/2Z. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put multiplicatively, your presentation is

$$\langle b,c\mid (bc)^2, bc=cb\rangle.$$

By [Tietze transformations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_transformations), introduce $a=bc$, so that $c=b^{-1}a$, giving the presentation

$$\langle a,b\mid a^2, a=(b^{-1}a)b\rangle,$$

which simplifies to

$$\langle a,b\mid a^2, ba=ab\rangle;$$

and [this presentation yields, multiplicatively, the group $\Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2376694/104041). This is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z\oplus \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$.

Comment: This is a very helpful answer! I’ve never heard of Tietze transformations, though I was using some of them. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, @Squeezemytheorem.