# Showing that the restricted wreath product $\Bbb Z\wr\Bbb Z$ is finitely generated.

Tags: group-theory, finitely-generated, infinite-groups, wreath-product

This is the first part of **Exercise 1.6.15** of Robinson's *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*. According to [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5CBbb%20Z%5Cwr%5CBbb%20Z%24%20finitely%20generated%20&p=8) and [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22wreath+product%22+of+%22integers%22+%22finitely+generated%22&client=ms-android-samsung-ss&biw=350&bih=280&sxsrf=ALeKk00doOVxYqtK-i8Vsb2uWsOe2DpUfA%3A1617225015783&ei=N-VkYMicL8yF9u8P-cijoA4&oq=%22wreath+product%22+of+%22integers%22+%22finitely+generated%22&gs_lcp=ChNtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1zZXJwEAMyBAgjECc6BwgjELACECdQodNGWILFR2D5z0doAHAAeACAAbcDiAGECJIBBzQuMi40LTGYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-serp#ip=1), it is new to MSE.

### The Details:

Robinson calls the restricted wreath product $H\wr K$ the *"standard wreath product"*. There is cause for confusion, as discussed in [this answer to a previous question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4083141/104041).

For clarity's sake, then, I'll share Robinson's definition here . . .

On page 32 and 33, *ibid.*,

> Let $H$ and $K$ be permutation groups on sets $X$ and $Y$ respectively. [. . .]
>
> If $\gamma\in H$, $y\in Y$, and $\kappa\in K$, define
>
> $$\gamma(y):\begin{cases} (x,y) \mapsto (x\gamma, y) & \\ (x,y_1) \mapsto (x,y_1) & y_1\neq y,\end{cases}$$
> and
>
> $$\kappa^\ast: (x,y)\mapsto (x,y\kappa).$$
>
> [. . .] The functions $\gamma\mapsto \gamma(y)$, with $y$ fixed, and $\kappa\mapsto \kappa^\ast$ are monomorphisms from $H$ and $K$ to ${\rm Sym}(X\times Y)$: let their images be $H(y)$ and $K^\ast$, respectively. Then the *wreath product* of $H$ and $K$ is the permutation group on $X\times Y$ [. . .]
>
> $$H\wr K=\langle H(y), K^\ast\mid y\in Y\rangle.$$
>
> [. . .]
>
> [T]he *base group* $B$ of the wreath product [is]
>
> $$B=\underset{y\in Y}{{\rm Dr}}\, H(y).$$

Here $\underset{y\in Y}{{\rm Dr}}\, H(y)$ is defined as in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4059459/104041).

---

*Standard Wreath Products:*

On page 41 of the book,

> If $H$ and $K$ are arbitrary groups, we can think of them as permutation groups on their underlying sets via the right regular representation and form their wreath product $W=H\wr K$: this is called the *standard wreath product*.

### The Question:

> Prove that the [standard/restricted] wreath product $\Bbb Z\wr \Bbb Z$ is finitely generated.

### Thoughts:

We have two copies of $\Bbb Z$ given by, say, the two presentations

$$\langle a\mid\rangle \quad\text{and}\quad\langle b\mid\rangle.$$

I am led to believe [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/w/index.php?title=Wreath_product_of_group_of_integers_with_group_of_integers&mobileaction=toggle_view_desktop) that $\Bbb Z\wr \Bbb Z$ is not finitely presented, so I'm not sure what to do with the presentations of $\Bbb Z$.

It appears that obtaining a presentation for a wreath product is, in general, somewhat of an active field of research; indeed, see again [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22wreath+product%22+of+%22integers%22+%22finitely+generated%22&client=ms-android-samsung-ss&biw=350&bih=280&sxsrf=ALeKk00doOVxYqtK-i8Vsb2uWsOe2DpUfA%3A1617225015783&ei=N-VkYMicL8yF9u8P-cijoA4&oq=%22wreath+product%22+of+%22integers%22+%22finitely+generated%22&gs_lcp=ChNtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1zZXJwEAMyBAgjECc6BwgjELACECdQodNGWILFR2D5z0doAHAAeACAAbcDiAGECJIBBzQuMi40LTGYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-serp#ip=1): there are papers as recent as 2018.

The reason I mentioned the two presentations is that perhaps the generators in question relate to $a$ and $b$ somehow.

---

*My Background:*

I'm used to finitely *presented* groups as part of my postgraduate research degree, which I am still undergoing. I don't have much experience, though, with nonfinitely presented groups.

A while ago, I asked this question:

[Describing the Wreath product categorically.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/867203/104041)

It concerns wreath products for *semigroups*.

---

The type of answer I would prefer is a conceptual explanation of why $\Bbb Z\wr\Bbb Z$ is finitely generated, not necessarily a *proof* of the fact, because I think I ought to be able to prove it myself.

Besides, I want to move on to Robinson's chapter on free groups and presentations.

---

Please help :)

Comment: https://berstein2015.wordpress.com/2015/06/15/wreath-products-and-finiteness/

Comment: That's an excellent find, @EricTowers. Thank you!

Comment: I’m not sure (I don’t know that much about group theory), but don’t you have (when $\mathbb{Z}$ acts on itself by translation) $n(m)=m^*n(0)(m^*)^{-1}$, $n(0)=1(0)^n$, and $m^*=(1^*)^m$, so that $1^*$ and $1(0)$ generate all your generators and hence the wreath product?

Comment: Maybe. What do you mean by $x^*$, @Mindlack?

Comment: The notation from Robinson’s restricted wreath product, I think.

Comment: Oh, of course! Thank you, @Mindlack.

Comment: Why not upgrade your comment to an answer, @Mindlack?

Comment: It is true more generally that, if $G$ and $H$ are finitely generated groups, then so is the restricted wreath product $G \wr H$.

Comment: Intuitively, you only need to get enough elements in the $e_K$-indexed copy of $H^{|K|}$ to generate $H$; and then enough elements of $K$ to generate all of $K$, since then you can “shift” the copy of $H$ around to any position using just the elements that generate $K$. So you can certainly generate $H\wr_rK$ with at most $m+n$ elements, where $m$ is the number of elements you need to generate $H$, and $n$ is the number of elements needed to generate $K$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m turning my comment into an answer (with more generality), as Shaun suggested.

Assume we’re in the setting of a standard wreath product, with groups $H$ and $K$ acting by right translation on themselves. With the Robinson notation, it’s not hard to see that for any $h \in H,y \in K$, we have $h(y)=y^*h(e)(y^{-1})^*$.

We can also see that $y \in K \longmapsto (y^{-1})^*$, and $h \in K \longmapsto (h^{-1})(e)$ are group homomorphisms. Thus the standard wreath product of $H$ and $K$ is generated by the $k^*$ and the $h(e)^*$, where $k$ runs through a system of generators for $K$ and $h$ runs through a set of generators for $H$.

In particular, if $H$ and $K$ are finitely generated, the standard wreath product is finitely generated.