# The Frattini subgroup of the standard Wreath product of two quasicyclic groups is the group itself.

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups, maximal-subgroup, wreath-product, frattini-subgroup

This is part of **Exercise 5.2.5** of Robinson's *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*. According to [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3AQuasicyclic%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24H%5Cwr%20K%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24G%3D%7B%5Crm%20Frat%7D(G)%24&p=10) and [this search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Wreath+product+quasicyclic+), it is new to MSE.

Here are some previous questions of mine about Wreath products:

- [Showing $Z(H\wr K)$, for abelian $H\neq 1$ and arbitrary $K$, is the diagonal subgroup of the base group.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4079892/104041)
- [Showing $Z(H\wr K)=1$, for abelian $H\neq 1$ and arbitrary, infinite $K$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4082857/104041)
- [Showing that the restricted wreath product $\Bbb Z\wr\Bbb Z$ is finitely generated.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4085628/104041)

### The Details:

*(This can be skipped.)*

On page 32 and 33, *ibid.*,

> Let $H$ and $K$ be permutation groups on sets $X$ and $Y$ respectively. [. . .]
>
> If $\gamma\in H$, $y\in Y$, and $\kappa\in K$, define
>
> $$\gamma(y):\begin{cases} (x,y) \mapsto (x\gamma, y) & \\ (x,y_1) \mapsto (x,y_1) & y_1\neq y,\end{cases}$$
> and
>
> $$\kappa^\ast: (x,y)\mapsto (x,y\kappa).$$
>
> [. . .] The functions $\gamma\mapsto \gamma(y)$, with $y$ fixed, and $\kappa\mapsto \kappa^\ast$ are monomorphisms from $H$ and $K$ to ${\rm Sym}(X\times Y)$: let their images be $H(y)$ and $K^\ast$, respectively. Then the *wreath product* of $H$ and $K$ is the permutation group on $X\times Y$ [. . .]
>
> $$H\wr K=\langle H(y), K^\ast\mid y\in Y\rangle.$$
>
> [. . .]
>
> [T]he *base group* $B$ of the wreath product [is]
>
> $$B=\underset{y\in Y}{{\rm Dr}}\, H(y).$$

Here $\underset{y\in Y}{{\rm Dr}}\, H(y)$ is defined as in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4059459/104041).

---

On page 41 of the book,

> If $H$ and $K$ are arbitrary groups, we can think of them as permutation groups on their underlying sets via the right regular representation and form their wreath product $W=H\wr K$: this is called the *standard wreath product*.

---

On page 94 of the book,

> [Let $p$ be prime and let] $P$ be the group with the generators $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots$ and relations
>
> $$pa_1=0,\quad pa_{i+1}=pa_i,\quad a_i+a_j=a_j+a_i,$$
>
> [then] $P$ is the [. . .] *quasicyclic $p$-group*.

---

On page 130 of the book,

> [B]y a *maximal subgroup* we mean a *proper* subgroup which is not contained in any larger proper subgroup.

On page 135 of the book,

> The *Frattini subgroup* of an arbitrary group $G$ is defined to be the intersection of all maximal subgroups, with the stipulation that it shall equal $G$ if $G$ should prove to have no maximal subgroups. This subgroup [. . .] is written
>
> $${\rm Frat}\, G.$$

. . . and . . .

> [A]n element  $g$ is called a *nongenerator* of $G$ if $G=\langle g, X\rangle$ always implies that $G=\langle X\rangle$ when $X$ is a subset of $G$.

### The Question:

> Let $H$ and $K$ be quasicyclic groups and write $G=H\wr K$ for the standard wreath product. Prove that $G={\rm Frat}\, G$.

### Thoughts:

Clearly $G$ is infinite.

---

By definition of ${\rm Frat}\, G$, we need to show $H\wr K$ has no maximal subgroups.

Suppose the prime that defines $H$ is $p$ and that of $K$ is $q$.

---

The following is on page 135.

> **Theorem 5.2.12:** (Frattini). In any group $G$ the Frattini subgroup equals the set of nongenerators of $G$.

Therefore, if every $g$ of $H\wr K$ is a nongenerator, then we are done.

Suppose $g\in G$ and $G=\langle g, X\rangle$ for some $X\subseteq G$. WLOG, $g\notin X$. I need to show $H\wr K=\langle X\rangle$. We have the presentation in the details above, which might help, but I'm not sure.

---

I'm not particularly comfortable with quasicyclic groups. However, the following defines a multiplicative group isomorphic to the quasicyclic $p$-group:

> $$\Bbb Z(p^\infty)=\{z\in\Bbb C\mid z^{(p^n)}=1\text{ for some }n\in\Bbb N\},$$

which can be found [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group) and in Kargapolov *et al.*'s *"Fundamentals of the Theory of Groups"*. I find it much easier to understand.

---

Suppose $M\le G$ is maximal. I can see, sort of, that $M$ cannot exist, because there is no limit on $n$ in the "$z^{(p^n)}=1$" part of the equivalent definition above.

---

I don't think I could answer this myself any time soon.

---

Please help :)