# Let $f: \Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z} \to G $ be an epimorphism, $\ker f$ be generated by $\langle (3,0),(0,5) \rangle$. What type of abelian group is $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism

Let $f: \Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z} \to G $ be an epimorphism, $\ker f$ be generated by $\langle (3,0),(0,5) \rangle$. What type of abelian group is $G$?

I don't even know the context of that question since I found it on the back of my abstract algebra book (without a connection to any particular topic). Any hint would be much appreciated.

EDIT (based on comment below): I know that since f is surjective then $G$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/\ker(f)$ so it is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/\langle(3,0),(0,5)\rangle$. I see that $3$ and $5$ are prime numbers, but I don't know what to say more.

Comment: Is it just looking for the word finite? Or maybe the exact isomorphism class?

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: Do you know the First Isomorphism Theorem?

Comment: I can answer this question. However, first of all, I would like you to provide context in the form of what you have tried, what similar questions you know the answer to, what you're studying, *etc.* Please do so in an [edit]. This site is for learning and not about answering questions with no effort on the part of the asker.

Comment: I know that since f is surjective then G is isomorphic to $ZxZ/ ker(f)$ so it is isomorphic to $ZxZ/<(3,0),(0,5)>$. I see that 3 and 5 are prime numbers, but I don't know what to say more.

Comment: @blackkay1 note that in this specific case $\langle (3,0),(0,5)\rangle=\langle 
 3\rangle\times\langle 5\rangle$. So can you deduce a bit more about the quotient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f$ is an epimorphism, we can apply the First Isomorphism Theorem to get $(\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z)/\ker f\cong G$.

Let $x=(1,0), y=(0,1)$. Then the presentation

$$\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\cong \langle x,y\mid x+y=y+x\rangle$$

is standard.

Note that $(3,0)=3x$ and $(0,5)=5y$. Then

$$\begin{align}
\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/\ker f &\cong \langle x,y\mid 3x, 5y, x+y=y+x\rangle\\
&\cong\Bbb Z_3\times \Bbb Z_5\\
&\cong \Bbb Z_{15},
\end{align}$$

where the final isomorphism holds by the Chinese remainder theorem and the fact that $\gcd(3,5)=1$.

Comment: Why is that presentation a standard? What if I had different generators that would not be  only prime numbers and zeros? Let's say that those would be $\langle (3,1),(8,2) \rangle$ and not $\langle (3,0),(0,5) \rangle$.

Comment: It is standard, @blackkay1, because $\Bbb Z\cong\langle a\mid \rangle$ as a free group of rank one, and the direct product of two presentations is as given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2376694/104041). And that's a separate question; if you're interested, I suggest you make a new post on it.

Comment: So you say that doing the same thing for different generators would not be that totally similar to that example?