# Classify $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/ \langle (3,1), (8,2) \rangle $ via fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism

I am trying to classify $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/ \langle (3,1), (8,2) \rangle $ via fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups. As I understand by different questions posted in here that's what I'm doing.

I started to research that topic by posting [that question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4327538/let-f-bbbz-times-bbbz-to-g-be-an-epimorphism-ker-f-be-generated/4327664?noredirect=1#comment9023121_4327664) and then got interested in different possible options.

According to the scheme provided by Shaun I would think that I need to write $x = (1,0)$ and $y = (0,1)$. By that I would obtain $(3,1) = 3x + y$ and $(8,2) = 8x + 2y$. But what to do next? As I understand, it is not isomorphic to any $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Have *Smith normal forms* been covered in your course already?

Comment: Look at the matrix $$\pmatrix{3&1\cr8&2\cr}.$$ The gcd of the entries is $d_1=1$ and the gcd of $2\times2$ minors is $d_1d_2=2$. Therefore using Smith normal forms tells us that the quotient $\simeq\Bbb{Z}_{d_1}\oplus\Bbb{Z}_{d_2}\simeq \Bbb{Z}_1\oplus\Bbb{Z}_2\simeq\Bbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: *Stacked bases theorem* is a good buzzword for searching.

Comment: Here the simplest way is undoubtedly to show that $\{(3,1),(4,1)\}$ is a basis of $\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{Z}$. That makes the quotient somewhat clear (and we have found a pair of stacked bases).

Comment: Also note that the method used in the linked question is correct only because of the very simple choice of generators.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, in Algebra II two semesters ago.

Comment: The method works, @freakish; see my answer below.

Comment: I would even accept your answer Shaun, since it's 'more in line' with the other quention linked to this one, but I have already accepted the answer of Parcly Taxel (which is also great).

Comment: You can still accept it, @blackkay1; it just takes it away from ParclyTaxel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithmic way of solving problems like this is to compute the [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) of the matrix formed by the ideal generators, which reveals the invariant factors. In this case the invariant factors are $1,2$, which means the group is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/(1)\oplus\mathbb Z/(2)=\mathbb Z_2$.

The following invertible elementary row/column operations convert the original matrix to Smith normal form:
$$\begin{bmatrix}3&1\\8&2\end{bmatrix}\to\begin{bmatrix}3&1\\2&0\end{bmatrix}\to\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\2&0\end{bmatrix}\to\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\2&0\end{bmatrix}\to\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be as defined in the question. We get

$$\begin{align}
\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/\ker f &\cong \langle x,y\mid 3x + y, 8x + 2y, x+y=y+x\rangle\\
&\cong\langle x,y\mid y=-3x, 8x+2y, x+y=y+x\rangle\\
&\cong\langle x\mid 8x-6x, x-3x=-3x+x\rangle\tag{1}\\
&\cong\langle x\mid 2x, -2x=-2x\rangle\\
&\cong\langle x\mid 2x\rangle\\
&\cong \Bbb Z_2,
\end{align}$$

where $(1)$ holds by the Tietze transformation of eliminating $y$ as $y$ can be written in terms of $x$.