# Given $H=\langle X_H\mid R_H\rangle$ and $K=\langle X_K\mid R_K\rangle$, find a presentation for Robinson's $H\circ K$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

According to [this search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgroup-theory%5D+%5Bgroup-presentation%5D+central+product+), this question is new to MSE.

### The Details:

Paraphrasing Robinson's, *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*, we have the following

> **Definition:** Let $G$ be a group. Then $G$ is the *central product* $G_1\circ\dots\circ G_n$ of its normal subgroups $G_i\unlhd G$ if:
>
> - $G=G_1G_2\dots G_n$,
> - $[G_i,G_j]=1$ for $i\neq j$, and
> - $$G_i\cap \prod_{j\neq i}G_j=Z(G).$$

(Here $Z(G)$ is the centre of $G$.)

This appears to differ, if I'm not mistaken, from contemporary definitions of "central product"; I am using Robinson's because I want to better understand **Exercise 5.3.7** from his book (and I have plenty of experience with group presentations).

> **Definition 2:** A *group presentation* $\langle X\mid R\rangle $ is the quotient of the free group $F_X$ generated by the elements of $X$ by the normal subgroup $\langle\langle R\rangle\rangle$ of $F_X$ generated by $R$, where $R$ is a set of words in $X\cup X^{-1}$; such words can be written as $u=v$ for $uv^{-1}$.

### The Question:

> Given $H=\langle X_H\mid R_H\rangle$ and $K=\langle X_K\mid R_K\rangle$, find a presentation for the central product $H\circ K$ in terms of $X_H, X_K, R_H, R_K$.

### Thoughts:

There's nothing about central products in the standard text for all things to do with group presentations, namely, Magnus *et. al*'s, *"Combinatorial Group Theory: Presentations of Groups in Terms of Generators and Relations."*

---

Let $H=\langle X_H\mid R_H\rangle$ and $K=\langle X_K\mid R_K\rangle$. Since, by definition, $[H,K]=1$ in $H\circ K$, I think

$$H\circ K\cong (H\times K)/Q$$

for some $Q\unlhd H\times K$. This is because

$$H\times K\cong \langle X_H\cap X_K\mid R_H\cap R_K\cap\{ hk=kh: h\in X_H, k\in X_K\}\rangle.$$

(A proof of that presentation of $H\times K$ is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2376694/104041).)

However, I don't know whether the relations $R_H, R_K$ hold for a presentation of $H\circ K$.

---

Of course, $H\cap K=Z(H\circ K)$.

---

Please help :)

Comment: It does not seem to me that there is enough information given to solve this. You would need generators for $Z(H)$ and $Z(K)$ and also an isomorphism $Z(H) \to Z(K)$, none of which can necessarily be deduced from the presentations. Also, Exercise 5.3.7 of Robinson does involve central products, but it is about the very special case of extraspecial $p$-groups.