# Each extra-special group of order $2^{2n+1}$ is a central product of $D_8$s or of $D_8$s and a single $Q_8$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, quaternions, dihedral-groups, p-groups

This is **Exercise 5.3.7(i)** of Robinson's, *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*. According to [this search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgroup-theory%5D+extra-special+central+product+), it is new to MSE.

This is a classification problem. [This Wikipedia entry](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extra_special_group#:%7E:text=A%20central%20product%20of%20two,groups%20of%20order%20p3.) describes the result.

### The Details:

Let $p$ be prime. A *$p$-group* is a group all of whose elements have order $p$.

Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group. Then $G$ is *extra-special* if $G'$ (the derived subgroup of $G$) and $Z(G)$ (the centre of $G$) coincide and have order $p$.

The *quaternion group* $Q_8$ is defined to be the group given by the presentation

$$\left\langle x,y\, \middle|\, x^{2^2}=1, y^2=x^2, y^{-1}xy=x^{-1}\right\rangle.$$

The *dihedral group* $D_8$ of order eight is the group given by the presentation

$$\left\langle r,s\,\middle|\,r^{2^2}, s^2, srs=r^{-1}\right\rangle.$$

Let $G$ be a group with normal subgroup $G_1,\dots, G_n$. Then $G$ is the *central product* $G_1\circ\dots\circ G_n$ of those normal subgroups if:

- $G=G_1G_2\dots G_n$,
- $[G_i, G_j]=1$ for $i\neq j$, and
- for all $i$, $$G_i\cap\prod_{j\neq i}G_j=Z(G).$$

Robinson claims that $Z(G_i)=Z(G)$.

### The Question:

Paraphrased:

> Consider an extra-special group $G$ of  order $2^{2n+1}$. Prove $G$ is a central product of the $D_8$s or a central product of $D_8$s and a single $Q_8$.

There is a hint (which I have paraphrased):

> Prove that a central product of two $D_8$s is a central product of two $Q_8$s.

### Thoughts:

I thought I'd rewrite the question in terms of group presentations, so I asked the following question:

[Given $H=\langle X_H\mid R_H\rangle$ and $K=\langle X_K\mid R_K\rangle$, find a presentation for Robinson's $H\circ K$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4355982/104041)

It turns out that it is insufficient to know presentations of groups $H,K$ in order to find a presentation of $H\circ K$.

---

I don't know how to use the hint, let alone prove what it suggests I prove. <strike>My guess, though, is that the parity of $n$ determines whether there is a $Q_8$ term in the central product (since, if I'm right, we can replace an even number of $Q_8$s by the same number of $D_8$s in the central product).</strike> According to the Wikipedia entry (cited above), the number of $D_8$s in the central product does not depend on the parity of $n$.

---

If $G$ is an extra-special $2$-group of order $2^{2n+1}$, then $G'=Z(G)\cong \Bbb Z_2$.

---

Previous, relevant questions of mine include:

- [Find the upper central series of $Q_{2^n}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4345985/104041)
- [Showing ${\rm Aut}(D_{2^n})\cong{\rm Aut}(Q_{2^n})$ for $n\ge 4$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4346437/104041)
- [Showing ${\rm Aut}(Q_{2^n})\cong{\rm Hol}(\Bbb Z_{2^{n-1}})$ for $n>3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4351221/104041)

---

Please help  :)

Comment: Robinson asserts that $Z(G_i)\le Z(G)$, from which it follows that $Z(G_i)=Z(G)$. I don't know what goes wrong with your example (if anything).

Comment: Thanks @Shaun, that comment has sorted it for me. I was astray.

Comment: You're welcome, @ancientmathematician.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Z:=Z(G) = \langle z \rangle$, with $z$ of order $2$.

Choose two non-commuting generators $a,b$ of $G$. Then $[a,b]=z$, and $H:=\langle a,b \rangle$ is extraspecial of order $8$, and hence is isomorphic to $D_8$ or $Q_8$.

Now let $c$ be another generator of $G$, not in $H$. If $c \not\in C_G(a)$, then $[c,a]=z$, so $[cb,a]=1$. Similarly, if $c \not\in C_G(b)$, then $[ca,b]=1$. So we can replace $c$ by an element in the same coset $cH$, to get $c \in C_G(H)$.

It follows that $G = HC_G(H)$. In fact this is a central product, and you can check that $C_G(H)$ is extraspecial of order $2^{2n-1}$. So, by induction, $C_G(H)$ is a central produce of groups isomorphic to $D_8$ or $Q_8$, and hence the same applies to $G$.

Now it should be clear that the result to be proved follows from $D_8 \circ D_8 \cong Q_8 \circ Q_8$.

I can't really give advice on proving the hint. They are both groups of order $32$, so you just have to work out an isomorphism (and you can check it in GAP).

BTW, this result is proved in various textbooks on group theory.

Comment: Thank you. I'll be sure to check other textbooks more closely in future. I have a copy of almost every group theory textbook going. The main one I check is Rotman's, *"An Introduction to the Theory of Groups (Fourth Edition)"*; its index has no mention of central products. Just in case I don't have any of them, which textbooks are you referring to?

Comment: I probably have older books on my shelves than you do! It's done in detail in Gorenstein's "Finite Groups", and also in Huppert's comprehensive German book "Endliche Gruppen I", but that might not be very useful! I hoped that it might be in Isaacs' book on Group Theory, but unfortunately it is only covered in exercises.

Comment: Thank you again. Upon reading this answer again, I have a couple questions. You say $|H|=8$ in the second paragraph but then say $|H|=2^{2n-1}$. Did you mean $|C_G(H)|=2^{2n-1}$? What are $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Yes I meant $|C_G(H)| = 2^{2n-1}$. $x$ and $y$ are pseudonyms $a$ and $b$.