# Find the Cayley Graph of $\langle a,b\mid a^2,b^2,(ab)^2\rangle$

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, cayley-graphs

I am trying to find the Cayley Graph the group $$G=\langle a,b\mid a^2,b^2,(ab)^2\rangle.$$

It is easy to prove that $G$ is isomorphic to the dihedral group $D_4$, and $G$ must have $8$ elements.

I am not able to find all of the elements.
[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

> **Lemma:** For any $x$ in a group $H$, we have $$x^2=e\iff x=x^{-1}.$$

*Proof:* Let $x\in H$. Suppose $x^2=e$. Multiply by $x^{-1}$ on, say, the left. Then

$$\begin{align}
x^{-1}&=x^{-1}e\\
&=x^{-1}x^2\\
&=(x^{-1}x)x\\
&=ex\\
&=x.
\end{align}$$

Conversely, suppose $x=x^{-1}$. Multiply on, say, the right by $x$. Then $x^2=xx=x^{-1}x=e$. $\square$

---

Since $a^2=b^2=(ab)^2=e,$ we have

$$\begin{align}
ab&=(ab)^{-1}\\
&=b^{-1}a^{-1}\\
&=ba,
\end{align}$$

so that, via [Tietze transformations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_transformations), the presentation is isomorphic to

$$\langle a,b\mid a^2, b^2, ab=ba\rangle,$$

which is a presentation for the Klein four group (as it is the [direct product of $\Bbb Z_2$ with itself](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2376694/104041)), the Cayley graph for which is easy to find.

It should look like this:

[image]

This image was found [here](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cayley_graph_V4_Klein_four-group.svg).

The red arrows are multiplying by $a$; the green arrows, by $b$; and the blue, $ab$.