# Express $\mathbb{Z}^2/B$ as a direct product of cyclic groups

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, quotient-group, free-abelian-group

In previous questions, I've proved that $B$ is a free abelian group of rank $2$. Then naturally $B$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z^2$, right? Then $\mathbb{Z}^2/B$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Isn't this just the trivial group?

How am I suppose to express it as a direct product?

Comment: If $A=\mathbb{Z}$, and $B=2\mathbb{Z}$, then $B$ is "naturally" isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. Is $A/B=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}$? (Not sure what you mean by "naturally isomorphic" as usually 'natural' has a technical meaning, and it is unlikely that this is what you have here; hence the scare quotes)

Comment: A free abelian group of rank two is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$, however $\mathbb{Z}^2$ has proper subgroups isomorphic to itself.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Doesn't the Fundamental Theorem of Abelian Groups guarantees that $\mathbb{Z}^2$ cannot be partitioned? Also, even if $\mathbb{Z}^2$ does have proper isomorphic subgroups, it doesn't change the fact that $\mathbb{Z}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$ gives the trivial group?

Comment: @everwith you're right about $\mathbb{Z}^2 / \mathbb{Z}^2$ but that's just one case. You have have some other quotients to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $\Bbb Z\cong 2\Bbb Z\cong 3\Bbb Z$.

Let $G=\langle a,b\mid ab=ba\rangle\cong \Bbb Z^2$.

Suppose

$$\begin{align}
B&:=\langle a^2,b^2\rangle_G \\
&\cong 2\Bbb Z\times 2\Bbb Z\\
&\cong \Bbb Z^2.
\end{align}$$

Then

$$\begin{align}
G/B&\cong \langle a,b\mid ab=ba\rangle/\langle a^2,b^2\rangle_G\\
&=\langle a,b\mid a^2, b^2, ab=ba\rangle\\
&\cong \Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_2.
\end{align}$$

But if

$$\begin{align}
H&:=\langle a^2,b^3\rangle_G \\
&\cong 2\Bbb Z\times 3\Bbb Z\\
&\cong \Bbb Z^2,
\end{align}$$

then

$$\begin{align}
G/H&\cong \langle a,b\mid ab=ba\rangle/\langle a^2,b^3\rangle_G\\
&=\langle a,b\mid a^2, b^3, ab=ba\rangle\\
&\cong \Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_3.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Just want to confirm, $\langle a,b\mid a^2, b^2, ab=ba\rangle$ = $\{ x\langle a^2\rangle\mid x\in \langle a\rangle\}\times \{ y\langle b^2\rangle\mid y\in \langle b\rangle\}$, right?

Comment: No, @everwith; here $\langle x, y\rangle_G$ is the subgroup of $G$ generated by $x$ and $y$. Basically, it is the subgroup given by all products in $G$ of $x$ and $y$ only.

Comment: Also $$\langle a, b\mid a^2, b^2, ab=ba\rangle\cong \langle a\mid a^2\rangle \times\langle b\mid b^2\rangle.$$

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2376694/104041), @everwith.