# Let $\Bbb Z*\Bbb Z=\langle a,b\rangle$ and $N=\{waba^{-1}b^{-1}w^{-1}:w\in\Bbb Z*\Bbb Z\}.$ Prove $\langle a,b\rangle/N$ is abelian

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, free-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z} = \langle a,b \rangle$  and $$N = \left\{w a b a^{-1} b^{-1}w^{-1}: w\in  \mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z} \right\}$$ the smallest normal subgroup that contains $\left\{ a b a^{-1} b^{-1}\right\}$. I want to prove that $\langle a,b \rangle / N$ is a abelian group.

Let $w,\tilde{w} \in \mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}$, then i have to show that $w\tilde{w} w^{-1}\tilde{w}^{-1} \in N$.
The words on $\langle a,b \rangle$ have two possible forms
$$
a^{\epsilon_1} b^{\epsilon_2}\cdots a^{\epsilon_{n-1}} b^{\epsilon_{n}}\quad \text{or }  \quad b^{\epsilon_1} a^{\epsilon_2}\cdots b^{\epsilon_{n-1}} a^{\epsilon_{n}}  
$$

where $\epsilon_{i}\in \mathbb{Z}$.
I try to make an induction on length of words, but some cases are very complicated for analyzing, I really feel that there is another way to prove this. ( I know this group is isomorphic to an abelian group, but I don't want to use that because I want to learn to understand the structure of free groups.)

Comment: It is sufficient to show that generators of the factor commute.

Comment: Note that your set $N$ is **not** the smallest normal subgroup that contains $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$. Your set is not even a subgroup: it does not contain the identity, is not closed under inverses, and is not closed under products. For example, you cannot express $a(aba^{-1}b^{-1})a^{-1}b(aba^{-1}b^{-1})b^{-1}$ as a conjugate of $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$. The smallest normal subgroup containing $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ is the subgroup **generated** by your set $N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $N$ is not a subgroup at all, let alone a normal subgroup. The smallest normal subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ that contains $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ is the subgroup *generated* by $N$; more generally, the least normal subgroup containing the set $S$ is the collection of all finite products of conjugates of elements of $S$ and their inverses.

To see that your set $N$ is not a subgroup, note that you cannot express the identity in the form $w(aba^{-1}b^{-1})w^{-1}$. Because if you could, then you would have $aba^{-1}b^{-1} = w^{-1}(e)w = e$, which is false. So $N$ does not contain the identity.

(It is also not closed under products, as $(aba^{-1}b^{-1})^2$ is no a conjugate of $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$, nor is it closed under inverses, since $(aba^{-1}b^{-1})^{-1} = bab^{-1}a^{-1}$ is also not a conjugate of $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$, though these are a bit harder to establish.)

So let $M$ be the smallest normal subgroup that contains $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$, that is, $M=\langle N\rangle$. Then $G/M$ is generated by $Ma$ and $Mb$. To show that a group generated by a set $S$ is abelian it suffices to show that the elements of $S$ commute with each other. Here, $Ma$ clearly commutes with itself, as does $Mb$. To show that $Ma$ commutes with $Mb$, note that $(ab)(ba)^{-1} = aba^{-1}b^{-1}\in M$, so
$$ (Ma)(Mb) = M(ab) = M(ba) = (Mb)(Ma).$$
Therefore, $G/M$ is indeed abelian.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

By definition of a presentation,${}^\dagger$ we have

$$\begin{align}
(\Bbb Z\ast\Bbb Z)/N&\cong\langle a,b\mid aba^{-1}b^{-1}\rangle\\
&\cong\langle a,b\mid ab=ba\rangle,
\end{align}$$

which defines an abelian group because the generators commute.

In fact, the quotient defines the group $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$, because $\Bbb Z\cong\langle x\mid\rangle$; see the following:

[Group Presentation of the Direct Product.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2376694/104041)

---

$\dagger$: As @ArturoMagidin points out in [his answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4687942/104041), the *set* you describe in your question is not a subgroup; the smallest normal subgroup containing $\{aba^{-1}b^{-1}\}$ *is*, however, and it's what I assume you mean by $N$ here.