# Why are $\langle (1634),(25)\rangle$ and $\langle (16),(34),(25)\rangle$ order-$8$ subgroups of $S_6$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $A=\langle (16342587)\rangle \le S_8$, $B=\langle (1634),(25)\rangle \le S_6$,  $C=\langle (16),(34),(25)\rangle \le S_6.$

Show that: $|A|=|B|=|C|=8$

I can understand why would $A$ would be order $8$ but can't understand the rest.

Wouldn't $B$ have an order of $4$ as the $\text{lcm}(4,2) = 4$, and similarly with $C$, wouldn't it be $2$?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: $C = \{ (), (1 6), (3 4), (2 5), (1 6)(3 4), (1 6)(2 5), (3 4)(2 5), (1 6)(3 4)(2 5)\}$. You are confusing it with $\langle (1 6)(3 4) (2 5)\rangle = \{(),(1 6)(3 4) (2 5)\}$.

Comment: $B\cong \mathbb Z_4\times \mathbb Z_2$ and $C\cong \mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$

Comment: Just use, for example, `Size(Group([ (1,6), (3,4), (2,5) ]));` in GAP.

Comment: One could argue that your question is in fact two.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

The generators of $B$ are disjoint as permutations and thus commute.

Let $a=(1634),b=(25)$. By the above, $ab=ba$. Also $|a|=4$ and $|b|=2$ by inspection. Thus

$$B\le\langle x,y\mid x^4, y^2, xy=yx\rangle\cong\Bbb Z_4\times \Bbb Z_2\tag{1}$$

by [this standard result](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2376694/104041). But $a^mb^n$ are clearly distinct for $0\le m\le 3$ and $0\le n\le 1$, which implies

$$8\le |B|\le |\Bbb Z_4\times \Bbb Z_2|=8.$$

Hence $|B|=8$.

---

The argument for $C$ is similar.

*Hint:*

> Consider $$\Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2\cong\langle r,s,t\mid r^2, s^2,t^2, rs=sr, rt=tr, st=ts\rangle.$$

---

*NB:* I abused notation in $(1)$. What I should have said is that $B$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of the group $G$ given by the presentation $$\langle x,y\mid x^4, y^2, xy=yx\rangle,$$ and $G$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_4\times\Bbb Z_2$. With experience, this subtlety gets glossed over with ease, but I couldn't leave it without an explanation, given that you're new to this.