# Symmetry group of an hourglass shape, the molecule Ferrocene.

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, symmetry, chemistry

I am starting to learn (Visual) Group Theory and I saw this hourglass shaped molecule Ferrocene:

[image: Ferrocene]

I am wondering what group is described by its symmetries. On top of the five rotations I think there are vertical $v$ and horizontal $h$ flips. Mapping its Cayley Diagram gave me $4$ cycles with flips acting as bridges between them. I've also noticed that $hv = vh$ which is reminiscent of the Klein group $V_4$. Is there a name for this "hourglass group"? And I feel like it could be separated into subcomponents like $V_4$ and a Cycle group of five elements $C_5$? Is there a way to formalize this?

Thanks a lot !
Pierrick

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes!

The group $G$ should be $D_5\times \Bbb Z_2$, where $D_5$ is the dihedral group of order ten.

If $a$ is a rotation of $2\pi/5$ counterclockwise from a bird's-eye view, $b$ is a horizontal symmetry from that view, and $c$ is a flip about the centre, then we have

$$\begin{align}
bab&=a^{-1},\\
 a^5&=e,\\
 b^2&=e, \\
c^2&=e,\\
 ac&=ca,\\
 bc&=cb,
\end{align}$$

which give the presentation

$$\begin{align}
D_5\times \Bbb Z_2&\cong\langle a,b\mid a^5, b^2, bab=a^{-1}\rangle \times\langle c\mid c^2\rangle \\
&\cong\langle a,b, c\mid a^5, b^2, c^2, bab=a^{-1},ac=ca, bc=cb\rangle
\end{align}$$

by [this standard result](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2376694/104041).

As we can see [here](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ematyd/GroupNames/1/D10.html) (in particular, [here](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ematyd/GroupNames/1/e3/C2%5E2byC5.html#s1), although it is very technical${}^\dagger$), we *can* use $\Bbb Z_2^2$ (*i.e.*, $V_4$) and $\Bbb Z_5$, but we would have to use the *semidirect product*:

$$\boxed{G\cong \Bbb Z_5\rtimes\Bbb Z_2^2.}$$

Also, $G\cong D_{10}.$

---

$\dagger$: The notation $\Bbb Z_5\rtimes\Bbb Z_2^2$ has some ambiguity. Really, it should be

$$\color{red}{\boxed{G\cong\Bbb Z_5\rtimes_\varphi\Bbb Z_2^2,}}$$

where, if $\mathbb{Z}_5 = \langle x\mid x^5 \rangle$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2^2 = \langle y, z\mid y^2,z^2, yz=zy \rangle$, we have the homomorphism

$$
\varphi:\Bbb Z_2^2\to\Bbb Z_2\le {\rm Aut}(\Bbb Z_5)$$

with $\varphi(y)(x) = x^{-1}$ and $\varphi(z)(x) = x. 
$ (This determines the whole map by the homomorphism property.)

Comment: Absent any context, the notation $\Bbb Z_5\rtimes\Bbb Z_2^2$ is ambiguous, right? In order to know what group is meant by $\Bbb Z_5\rtimes\Bbb Z_2^2$, we need to know what the intended homomorphism $\Bbb Z_2^2 \to \text{Aut}(\Bbb Z_5)$ is.

Comment: Indeed, yes, @TannerSwett; that is the reason behind the "in particular, here, although it is very technical" - it gives the three semidirect products, including the direct product, and the $D_{10}$ one should be highlighted in the link as well as by the labelling. I'll add a note to that effect now.

Comment: Is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4722785/7) better, @TannerSwett?

Comment: *two $${}{}{}{}{}$$ . . . not three.

Comment: Yes, thank you for adding that note! I remember that when I first encountered the semidirect product notation, I was very confused by the fact that the homomorphism was left unstated, so it's great to see that spelled out explicitly.