# Motivation for presentation of group $G$ in Hungerford’s Abstract Algebra

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, motivation

> An immediate consequence of Corollary 9.3 and the First Isomorphism Theorem is that any group $G$ is isomorphic to a quotient group $F/N$, where $G =\langle X\rangle$, $F$ is the free group on $X$ and $N$ is the kernel of the epimorphism $F\to G$ of Corollary 9.3. Therefore, in order to describe $G$ up to isomorphism we need only specify $X$, $F$, and $N$. But $F$ is determined up to isomorphism by $X$ (Theorem 7.8) and $N$ is determined by any subset that generates it as a subgroup of $F$. Now if $w=x_1^{\delta_1}\cdots x_n^{\delta_n}$ is a generator of $N$, then under the epimorphism $F\to G$, $w\mapsto  x_1^{\delta_1}\cdots x_n^{\delta_n} = e \in G$. The equation $ x_1^{\delta_1}\cdots x_n^{\delta_n} = e$ in $G$ is called a relation on the generators $x_i$. Clearly a given group G may be completely described by specifying a set $X$ of generators of $G$ and a suitable set $R$ of relations on these generators. This description is not unique since there are many possible choices of both $X$ and $R$ for a given group $G$ (see Exercises 6 and 9).

**Question:** I don’t exactly get why we need $R$ to specify $G$. Isn’t $G$ completely described by $X$? I mean $G=\langle X\rangle$.

Sentence “Now if $w=x_1^{\delta_1}\cdots x_n^{\delta_n}$ is a generator of $N$, then under the epimorphism $F\to G$, $w\mapsto  x_1^{\delta_1}\cdots x_n^{\delta_n} = e \in G$” is bit convoluted, in my opinion. It simply say, if $w\in N$, then $w=e$. So $R=N$.

Comment: "Isn't $G$ completely described by $X$?" The generating set by itself doesn't give you any relations. For example if I told you $\{1,\cdots,8\}$ had a group operation on it, and that group was generated by $\{1,2\}$, would you be able to tell if the group is even abelian?

Comment: In this context, what you really have is a function $f\colon X\to G$, you know $X$ and $f$, and you know that $G$ is generated by the image of $f$; you do not have any information about what the group operation on $G$ is, or how elements of $X$ multiply together (because they don't;  it's their image in $G$ which can multiply together).

Comment: @coiso if I know group operation explicitly, then yes.

Comment: The whole point of a presentation is to give you information that  allows you to *deduce* what the group operation is, based on information about a set that generates the group and certain identities that hold among those elements. You do not "know" $\circ$; you know $\circ$ *exists*, and you are providing information that allows you to (re)construct it. The presentation is a lot less information than the function $\circ$. E.g., a cyclic group of order $n$ is determined by two pieces of information, a generating set $x$ and the identity $x^n=1$. The operation is a set of $n^2$ pairs.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Your comment make sense. I will spend more time thinking about your comment.

Comment: Presentations are exceedingly useful. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2376694/104041) for instance.